# After removing dual boot, Windows 10 didn't boot. It shows me only a black screen and cursor after Windows logo. How do I fix it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, black-screen-of-death, bcd

I had Windows 11 as **bootable** next to Windows 10 but when I removed the 11's partition and rebuilt BCD and **MBR** for 10's partition, It didn't boot. It shows me only a black screen and cursor after Windows logo. How do I fix it?

Tried “`sfc /scannow /offbootdir:c: /offwindir:c:\windows`” via USB recovery Windows ISO, yet It returns this:

> Windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation

Tried `bootrec /fixboot` yet it returns this:

> Access is denied

**DISM** didn’t work either, and I don't remember the syntax I used but It returns **error 87**.
Tried auto fix of the recovery environment, It didn’t work either.
Note: I have only one partition: **C:**\ not using System Reserved.
Note2: **CTRL+ALT+DEL** doesn’t work either on the black screen.
Note3: At first Windows 10 was installed to the end of disk and When I removed Windows 11 in the beginning of the disk I tried to copy Windows 10 to the beginning of the disk using Gparted as I didn’t want it to stay to the very end of the disk after my Linux partition but still the partition moved completely with no problem. (*just to make sure this didn’t make a problem itself*.)

Comment: If you a Windows recovery USB, use it to do Startup Repair. Have you deleted more than one partition?

Comment: I have done Startup Repair like I said. I only deleted Windows 11 partition.

Comment: I can't see [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html) in your post.

Comment: "Tried auto fix of the recovery environment"

Comment: It seems that I broke registry entries this time as well. I will reinstall the Windows anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to sermon the task manager and browse to activate the windows explorer.